# Кнопка с двумя строками текста (Android)

Tags: android

Есть signup_button.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/signup_background_states" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/authSignupText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/auth_register"
        android:textSize="@dimen/auth_register"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/authSignupSubtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/auth_register_subtext" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Надо чтобы менялся цвет текста, когда кнопка находится в нажатом состоянии. Отнаследовался от LinearLayout, вызвал linearlayout.inflate(R.layout.signup_button, this, true). Чтобы менять цвет текста, я переопределяю метод onDraw:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c){
    if(isPressed()){
        text.setTextColor(ec);
        subtext.setTextColor(ec);
    } else {
        text.setTextColor(rc);
        subtext.setTextColor(sc);
    }
    super.onDraw(c);
}
```

Но кнопка не реагирует на нажатия, и цвет текста тоже не меняется. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо использовать т.н. **state selector**, типа:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" 
            android:color="#ffffff" />     
   <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
            android:color="#000000" />     
   <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
            android:color="#000000" />     
   <item android:color="#ffffff" /> 
</selector>
```

Сохранить его в res/drawable/my_button_selector.xml и сослаться на него в лэйауте:

```
android:textColor="@drawable/my_button_selector"
```

Comment: Попробовал, не работает. Проблема ещё в том, что мне надо, чтобы текст в этих TextView был разного цвета.

Comment: Поройтесь здесь http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+textview+selector

Comment: Видимо, неправильно искал :) Открыл для себя свойство duplicateParentState. Благодарю.